# User Rcpp on Windows Machine with Multiple g++ installs

Tags: r, rcpp

I am attempting to look into using Rcpp with R.  I am using a windows 7 machine and unfortunately installed several different compilers for different projects (python...).  When I tried to execute the provided example in the Rcpp package I got an error.  The code that I attempted was the following:

```
CFib = cppFunction(
  'int fibonacci(const int x) {
        if (x == 0) return(0); 
        if (x == 1) return(1);
        return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2);
    }')
```

This failed with the following message from the console:

```
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/Users/jclutter/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include"  -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c file1c205fb26c00.cpp -o file1c205fb26c00.o
file1c205fb26c00.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
 #include <Rcpp.h>
 ^
make: *** [file1c205fb26c00.o] Error 1
Warning message:
running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="sourceCpp_22135.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="file1c205fb26c00.o"' had status 2 
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

I realize this is because it is most likely using a compiler that did not have 64-bit compiled in.  I have the Rtools version 3.1 installed but it is not part of my path (not sure why).  Vice inserting yet another compiler into my path, I thought I could use a Rcpp Plugin to address the issue.  The following is the code that I attempted to use:

```
rtoolsplug = Rcpp.plugin.maker(
  Makevars = 'CXX = c:/Rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/g++.exe',
  Makevars.win = 'CXX = c:/Rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/g++.exe'
)
registerPlugin('rtools', rtoolsplug)

CFib = cppFunction(
  'int fibonacci(const int x) {
        if (x == 0) return(0); 
        if (x == 1) return(1);
        return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2);
    }',
  plugins = c('rtools')
  )
```

When I execute this I get the following error (spoiler, it is the same):

```
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/Users/jclutter/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include"  -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c file1c206a9e1cf1.cpp -o file1c206a9e1cf1.o
file1c206a9e1cf1.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
 #include <Rcpp.h>
 ^
make: *** [file1c206a9e1cf1.o] Error 1
Warning message:
running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="sourceCpp_94004.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="file1c206a9e1cf1.o"' had status 2 
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

I thought that for sure I would be able to fix this with a plugin.  Am I attempting to do this incorrectly?

For completeness here are the versions of my software:

- Windows 7
- R: 3.1.1
- Rtools: 3.1 (Not in path for some reason)
- Rcpp: 0.11.2

Comment: Read the _Writing R Extensions_ and _R Installation and Administration_ manuals **very carefully** and set your path up correctly.  There is really nothing more to it: you need the proper tools, properly setup and with the correct path for Rtools and _its_ g++ compiler.

Comment: Ok, I understand that if I want Rcpp to work out of the box I must do these things...  Am I incorrect in thinking that I am hard code the compiler to use through the plugins method?

Comment: I already stated that there is nothing to it.  Set the tools up, and Rcpp works out of the box. If you insist on doing it differently and it breaks, you get to keep the pieces.

Comment: lol...  I simply hate the idea of having to modify my path each time I switch to different tools.  Ok, all that being said, can you tell me why the Makevars is not being honored in the above code?

Comment: For this particular instance, you could automate it by having some code in your `~/.Rprofile` that automatically sets the appropriate environment variables upon R session startup (assuming you're mainly interested in having this work within R)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by carefully reading the R install guide and implementing a local user based Makevars.win file.  The Makevars.win file is a special makefile that is pulled into the other internal makefiles that R uses for compilations.  In the Makevars.win file, one can reset or update Makefile variables that are relevant for the build process.  The Makevars.win file I used is the following:

```
PATH := c:/Rtools/bin;C:/Rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin;$(PATH)
CXX  = c:/Rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/g++.exe -m64
```

I am not sure if I did this entirely correct and I frown upon it since it has hardcoded values.  I do wish that there was a way to tell R to use the Rtools as the default building tools and then only use locally installed tools when specifically requested.

Of special note is the location of the Makevars.win file.  The manual states that it should be placed in the users home directory underneeth a directory called `.R`.  The manual should be updated to highlight that the home directory is not the same as %USERPROFILE% or any other commonly defined environment variable.  The users home directory, in the R sense, can be found by executing the `show.file('~')` command.  In my case this was:

```
c:\Users\<MYNAME>\Documents\.R\Makevars.win
```

I hope that this helps other people use the Makevars.win in the future.

Using this setup I waws able to use the above Rcpp code without the plugin elements.  I do think that there is some confusion with regard to the plugin system for Rcpp.  Based on what I have read it should work the way that I had attempted to use it.  I will be investigating this in the future.  I think that it would be a vary clean way to adjust these settings as needed on the fly.  Something that I was looking for from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this batch file https://batchfiles.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rpathset.bat to be correct for your system (most of the paths will be correct already or close to correct) and then run the following from the Windows cmd line:

```
Rpathset.bat
Rgui
```

This will temporarily set the appropriate path and run R.  Note that no settings on your system will be permanently changed.  Its only temporary for the current cmd line session.

**Note:** `Rpathset.bat` is part of the batchfiles distribution but you don't need any other files from it if all you want to do is the above.  Home page: https://batchfiles.googlecode.com

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I would like to find something that is closer to adjusting the build environment without the need to modify the global install and the need to execute a script prior to R's startup.  In the end I did do something similar which I will post as an answer below.

Comment: That is not entirely correct. In fact, this makes no global changes.  It only changes the current console session.  Other console sessions on the same machine at the same time are not affected and no permanent changes are made at all.